# JSONPath Query to get Node-names?

Tags: php, json, jsonpath

Consider the following piece of JSONPath:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "type":"Residence",
         "street":"Piazza di Spagna",
         "city":"-4:0"
      },
      {
         "type":"Residence",
         "street":"test",
         "city":"-4:1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to get a list of all the node-names?
So for example, I want a list like: type, street, city.

Comment: Why not to use Javascript interpreter for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
$arr = (json_decode($json)->result[0]);
 $array = get_object_vars($arr);
 $properties = array_keys($array);
 print_r($properties);`
```

Out put will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => type
    [1] => street
    [2] => city
)
```

Answer (score 4):

On PHP >= 5.4 you can obtain your keys with one line of code:

```
$nodeNames = array_keys( json_decode( $jsonString, True )['result'][0] );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/AQakY)**</kbd>

On lower versions (PHP >= 5.2.16), you have to break above code in two lines:

```
$array = json_decode( $jsonString, True );
$nodeNames = array_keys( $array['result'][0] );
```

I decode the JSON string with second parameter as True to force result as array, then I call `array_keys` to obtain the keys of `array['result'][0]`.

#### Edit: more flexibility

Your example can be processed as above without problems, but what happens if original JSON string has different keys? The above solution will fail if in the first `result` row there are not all the keys. To obtain **all** the keys, you can use this code:

```
$array  = json_decode( $jsonString, True );
$nodeNames = array();
foreach( $array['result'] as $row )
{
    $nodeNames = array_unique( array_merge( $nodeNames, array_keys( $row ) ) );
}
```

or, using `array_filter`, with this code:

```
$array  = json_decode( $jsonString, True );
$nodeNames = array();
array_filter
(
    $array['result'], 
    function( $row )
    {
        global $nodeNames;
        $nodeNames = array_unique( array_merge( $nodeNames, array_keys( $row ) ) );
    }
);
```

By this two equivalent examples, I process each `result` row, merging the keys in `$nodeNames` array and using `array_unique` to delete duplicate keys.

---

- Read more about [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
- Read more about [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- Read more about [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function to print all keys in an array format

print_r(array_keys($array));

Answer (score 1):

Is the JSON Path **definitely** going to follow that structure every time? As in Result => Arrays all of which have the same Nodes.

If it does then the following will work:

```
function getJsonNodes($json) {
    $nodes   = array();
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);

    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid JSON String passed to getJsonNodes()');
    }

    $result = $decoded['result'];
    if (is_array($result)) {
        $nodes = array_keys($result[0]);
    }

    return $nodes;
}
```

Usage would be something like:

```
try {
    $nodes = getJsonNodes($json);
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Means you can catch any Invalid JSON strings that could potentially be passed and mess with the output.

Although as I stated, the above solution will only work if your JSON Path follows the structure to put in your OP.

You can see it in use here: https://ideone.com/dlvdu2

Hope it helps either way.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get a list of `all the node-names`?

```
$object = json_decode($json);
$json_array = $object->result;
foreach ($json_array as $key => $value) {
    $object_var = get_object_vars($value);
    $object_key = array_keys($object_var);
    var_dump($object_key);//will get all node_names!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$result[0].type , $result[0].street, $result[0].city
```

Comment: The OP is trying to get the attribute names, the `type`, `street` and `city`.

Comment: Then try: `$a = array('type', 'street', 'city');`

Answer (score -2):

Please check the below code ..Hope will work

```
<?php
$text[]=array(
            result=>array(
                "type"=>"Residence",
                "street"=>"pizza",
                "city"=>"ini"
            ),
            array(
                "type"=>"Residence",
                "street"=>"pizza",
                "city"=>"ini"
            )
        );

echo json_encode($text);
?>
```